# Read a file into an array

Tags: arrays, r

The following code create a array with n random values:

```
d = array(NA,c(2,n),dimnames=list(c("x","y"),paste("s", 1:n, sep="")))
d[1,] = sort(runif(n))
d[2,] = (runif(n))
```

Now, I have to replace the random generation by code which is reading a file and uses this values of the file for the array.

The content of the txt-file looks like:

```
1 7810 6053
2 7798 5709
3 7264 5575
4 7324 5560
5 7547 5503
6 7744 5476
7 7821 5457
8 7883 5408
9 7874 5405
10 7927 5365
11 7848 5358
12 7802 5317
13 7962 5287
```

Each line has the linenumber and the x and y value.

I am newbie working with R. Can someone help me to do this? - Thank you.

Comment: `d <- t(as.matrix(read.table(...)))[-1,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
read.table('data.txt', col.names = ('linenumber', 'x', 'y'))
```

Comment: this combined with jogo's comment to the answer, it is what I am looking for ... thank you.